# chained proxy in delphi

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy, chained

I just read about chaining proxies and i wanted to try it in delphi, 
well i played around with indy `TIdHttp` component and i couldnt figure out how to do it, 
do i need two `TIdHttp` components? maybe one sends the request to another?

```
  http1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := Port1;
  http1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Server1;

  http2.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := Port2;
  http2.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Server2;
```

I just want to send some simple GET/POST with the chained proxies.

Is that even doable? or are there any other component to help me with this task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property does not support chaining.

To use chained proxies, you need to:

1. Assign a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property.  Either:

   a. `TIdIOHandlerStack`, which is Indy's standard TCP/IP implementation.

   b. a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`. You must use this if you want to work with HTTPS urls.
2. Assign a `TIdCustomTransparentProxy`-derived component to the IOHandler's `TransarentProxy` property. Indy provides two such components by default:

   a. `TIdSocksInfo`, which implements the SOCKS 4/4a/5 protocols.

   b. `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy`, which implements the HTTP `CONNECT` verb.
3. Chain multiple `TIdCustomTransparentProxy`-derived components together via the `TIdCustomTransparentProxy.ChainedProxy` property.